# 'pie' function in MATLAB gives "undefined function 'cos'" error

Tags: matlab, plot, charts

I wrote a function, `wins_plot`, to read the scoreboard from a file and store the player's name, number of plays, wins, & losses. I stored all those using struct. I loop over the file, store each line in `line`, `textscan` for everything I need from `line`, and then iterate `i` (initially == 1) as I go to expand my array of structures. A snippet from the code to represent what I am saying:

```
c = textscan(line, '%s %s %d %d %d');

  player(i).firstName = c{1};
  player(i).lastName = c{2};
  player(i).plays = c{3};
  player(i).wins = c{4};
  player(i).losses = c{5};
```

After all the file has been scanned and stored, I then write this code to extract the number of wins of each player and store it in X and then finally use the pie function to represent the values in X

```
for n=1:(i-1)
    X(n) = player(n).wins;
end
pie(X);
```

I get a wall of error after:

> Undefined function 'cos' for input arguments of type 'int32'.
>
> Error in pol2cart (line 22) x = r.*cos(th);
>
> Error in pie (line 99)
>       [xtext,ytext] = pol2cart(theta0 + x(i)*pi,1.2);
>
> Error in wins_plot (line 30) pie(X);

I have no clue what might be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please keep in mind that I only just started learning MATLAB today so my knowledge of it is very limited (and I have R2013a). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers got read as `int32`, but when you call `pie`, it requires them to be double to do the computation. So, when you call `pie`, try casting the values to `double`. Try this,

```
pie(double(X));
```

Comment: @royabousamra MATLAB interprets all numbers as complex double precision values (unlike most languages) which is why `pie(1)` works but `pie(int32(1))` doesn't.

Comment: @jodag alright, that's good to know. Thanks for informing me! I know a good amount of C so MATLAB isn't that hard, but there are some specifications and details that I've yet to study/know.